# Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown

Tags: mysql, shutdown

```
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Instance 0, restricted to 2048 pages due to innodb_buf_pool_dump_pct=25
2020-10-01 18:30:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 201001 18:30:05
2020-10-01 18:30:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 11518008272; transaction id 28700995
2020-10-01 18:30:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-10-01 18:30:07 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

There is a process or something that is causing the Mysql server to shut down, but I don't know what it is.

I use:

Debian 10
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.23-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

When the server started:

```
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.23 started; log sequence number 11518008272; transaction id 28700996
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.23-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
2020-10-01 18:40:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201001 18:40:42
```

Comment: It's seems mariadb have a bug and they working on them https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?t=3720 . You need downgrade or upgarde to another version

Comment: Per https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20261, this was introduced in 10.4 and fixed in 10.5.5 so any version <10.4,>=10.5.5 should do. Given this is 10.3 I'm assuming it's not even the same bug.

Comment: yes @Ginnungagap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted the server and problem solved

¯_(ツ)_/¯